# tcpdf and digital signature certification

Tags: php, pdf, ssl, digital-signature, tcpdf

I'm trying to do a simple pdf certificate signing in php with tcpdf.

I'm running [example 52](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_052.phps) but the information on my pdf reader (osx preview) says:

**Encryption**: No

**Permissions:**
You have full permissions for this PDF. You can copy text, print or make changes to the PDF and save.

And clicking the signature logo does nothing.

Am I doing something wrong or is this just plain broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, apparently it works.

The problem was that OSX's preview doesn't show certificates.

I opened the PDF with Acrobat Reader and there it was.